# PHPExcel file not in the proper Microsoft Excel 2003 XLS format

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

I'm generating a Excell 2003 using PHPExcel 1.8 with this code:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('toUploadFtp.xls');
```

The file seems ok, and I can read it using MS Office and LibreOffice.

But I have to upload the file to a system that says the format has to be Excell 2003, and he prompts next error:

> Oops! Your file is not in the proper Microsoft Excel 2003 XLS format.

If I open the file with LibreOffice and save it again, then I can upload the file correctly to the system.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: So what is this system that doesn't recognise the file as a valid BIFF-format xls file when both MS Excel and Libre Office do recognise it as valid?

Comment: If all does not help, and only data is concerned, you may write CSV and save it (faking) as `.xls`. This lets Excel read it.

Comment: @Joop - MS Excel can read this file quite happily, as can LibreOffice; it's this unknown system that file file is uploaded to that can't read it

Comment: Are you transferring the file to your upload application in binary mode?

Comment: I've compared the XLS valid with the XLS generated by PHPExcel with Beyond Compare, and the only difference is the last line:
`... Unknown Creator 0 @ {nothing} @ ...`
vs `... Unknown Creator 0 @ Ф┴дл @ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I couldn't find a solution. It has to be some kind of bug in the XLS 2003 format.

But I generated a XLSX with `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');` and the system recognizes it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Create your file by passing the proper version to factory:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I put that and I receive this error: `Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2003' not found in ...`

Comment: Try `Excel2007` instead.

Comment: It doesnt work, for Excel2007 says the same. Excel 2007 is xlsx extension, not xls

Answer (score 1):

Not understanding the *exact* problem entirely: it seems to be with the additional transfer of the Excel file.

One error is often, that the PHP script outputs spurious data.

Leaving out the final `%>` is a standard trick to make sure no extra final new line characters are added to the file.

Comparing the files generated and transferred should yield insight on what went wrong.

You may need to set the content to non-text to prevent some text conversion:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet'):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can overcome this problem in changing the filed of `Excel5`.Since i havnt tried phpexcel i dont know much about this..But i think you can find a solution for this [here].[1](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/10059)